# Duvida classes c++

Tags: c++, classes

Bom dia galera! Estou vendo classes é vi essa sintaxe num dos exemplos:

```
vector<line *>line_table;
vector<line *>::iterator iterator;
line parser * basic_parser;
long current_line;
```

O que significa esse *template* com `<line *>` (`vector <line *>line_table`) , alguém pode me explicar o contexto ?

Comment: Qual contexto? A pergunta está ruim justamente por faltar um. Adicione informações que torne a pergunta compreensível.

Comment: Alexsander, sugiro que preste atenção nos comentários que os outros usuários deixam em suas perguntas, eles geralmente tem dicas valiosas para que você possa deixar sua pergunta clara e respondível para os membros da comunidade.

Answer (score 1):

A STL inclui varias estruturas de dados ao desenvolvedor uma delas é o vector, que é um vetor dinamico, há varias outras estruturas uma pesquisa rapida e você vera seus recursos.

Esta é implementada com metodo template de modo que possa ser reaproveitada para qualquer tipo que se deseja utilizar, qualquer classe declarada que exista um metodo template deve acompanhar junto a ela o tipo que se deseja trabalhar, ou seja, o que esta entre chaves como no exemplo abaixo:

```
pilha<int> a; // Uma pilha de inteiros
a.empilhar(1); // Empilha inteiros

pilha<pessoa> p; // Uma pilha de pessoas
p.empilhar(new pessoa("João", "155155155-15")) // Instancia uma nova pessoa e a empilha
```

Em suma, *vector line_table;* é um vetor de ponteiros para line... Ou seja, um vetor dinamico que armazena endereços de instancias de line

```
vector<line *> line_table;
line l_exemplo; // Instancia de line
line_table.push_back(&l_exemplo); // inseri no final do vetor o endereço da variavel l_exemplo
```

Não se esquecendo que o & antes da variavel indica endereço de memoria da variavel e não conteudo da varivel... Pesquisar por ponteiros caso não tenha conhecimento de ponteiros... Caso queira mais detalhes sobre templates (como criar por exemplo) pesquisar sobre templates

Answer (score 0):

`vector<line *> line_table` significa que você está criando um vector de ponteiros para o tipo `line`.

É difícil falar mais coisa já que não tem tanta informação do que você está tentando fazer. Mas a grosso modo, é isso que significa o template `<line *>`